# Trying to install smlnj on Ubuntu 10.04, REPL not working

Tags: 10.04, apt

I have installed smlnj using `sudo apt-get install smlnj`, but when I try to run it on the CLI using `sml`, I get this error `/usr/lib/smlnj/bin/.run/run.x86-linux: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.

I found this documentation http://www.smlnj.org/dist/working/110.75/NOTES/INSTALL that suggested that you also need to have 32-bit support, so I also installed these suggested packages: `apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib ia32-libs`, but I still get the same error. Is there a different package that I need, or do I need to add something to my bash configuration to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-installing, running these commands:

For 32bit:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/48337000/smlnj_110.72-1_i386.deb; sudo dpkg -i ./smlnj_110.72-1_i386.deb; rm ./smlnj_110.72-1_i386.deb; sudo apt-get -f install
```

For 64bit:

```
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/48558006/smlnj_110.72-1_amd64.deb; sudo dpkg -i ./smlnj_110.72-1_amd64.deb; rm ./smlnj_110.72-1_amd64.deb; sudo apt-get -f install
```